# MySQL error - "check syntax to use near '%s"

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Anyone see why the query below would yield the error

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)"?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id
FROM (
     SELECT taba.id
FROM (

SELECT alum.id
FROM cvm_education AS edu
JOIN cvm_alumni AS alum ON alum.id = edu.alumni_id
WHERE cvm_alumni.profile_status =1
AND highest_edu
IN (

SELECT name
FROM cvm_filter_educationlevels
JOIN cvm_educationlevel AS edulevels ON educationlevel_id = edulevels.id
WHERE filter_id = % s
)
) AS taba
```

Cheers!

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket - you have three opens and only two  closes

Comment: Noticed that, but not sure where to add last bracket

Comment: @nv39 something like this `) AS taba  ) xxx`

Comment: thanks - I had tried that before but kept getting errors so assumed it was wrong :P. Tried again and get "every derived table must have its own alias" error! argggh

Comment: @nv39 Can you provide a table structure with some sample data?

Comment: JOIN cvm_educationlevel AS edulevels ON educationlevel_id = edulevels.id - I think you also need to specify the table name for the first part of the argument so change it to (I assume) cvm_filter_educationlevels.educationlevel_id=edulevels.id

Comment: @nv39 I am willing to help you but you have to provide the table structure and a small amount of sample data.

Comment: Is it something like? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8adc/1

Comment: @nv39 Just curious, how did you solve it? You first mentioned that JW.'s answer didn't work and then a couple of hours later you have accepted his answer.

Comment: @Mr.Radical actually, the problem was here "WHERE cvm_alumni.profile_status =1"; this should have been "WHERE alum.profile_status" to reflect the alias that was created the step before

Comment: oops just realized that's what you suggested :p - so in fact your answer is best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT count(taba.id)
FROM (

SELECT alum.id
FROM cvm_education AS edu
JOIN cvm_alumni AS alum ON alum.id = edu.alumni_id
WHERE alum.profile_status =1
AND highest_edu
IN (

SELECT name
FROM cvm_filter_educationlevels
JOIN cvm_educationlevel AS edulevels ON educationlevel_id = edulevels.id
WHERE filter_id = 1
)
) AS taba ;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8adc/15

Two important points:

1. I don't understand the use of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS() if have chanced
   it in count(). I think this provides the same desired result.
2. You haven't provided sample data so I wasn't able to try %s. I have
   substituted it with a binary (1,0). Furthermore, I don't know your
   exact code so I made some assumptions based on your query.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE cvm_education(
  ID int auto_increment primary key,
  alumni_id int
  );

CREATE TABLE cvm_alumni(
  ID int auto_increment primary key,
  profile_status int,
  highest_edu varchar(30)
  );

CREATE TABLE cvm_filter_educationlevels (
  ID int auto_increment primary key,
  educationlevel_id int,
  name varchar(30)
  );

CREATE TABLE cvm_educationlevel(
  ID int auto_increment primary key,
  filter_id int
  );

INSERT INTO cvm_education (alumni_id)
VALUES (10), (1), (2), (3),(5), (6),(7),(8),(9);

INSERT INTO cvm_alumni (profile_status, highest_edu)
VALUES (1, "master"), 
(0,"bachelor"), 
(1,"bachelor"), 
(0, "master"),
(1, "master"),
(0, "master"),
(1, "master"),
(1, "master"), 
(1, "master"),
(1, "master");

INSERT INTO cvm_filter_educationlevels(educationlevel_id,name)
VALUES (1, "master"), (0,"bachelor");

INSERT INTO cvm_educationlevel(filter_ID)
VALUES (1), (0), (1), (0), (0), (1),(1),(1),(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to quote the string value and use `LIKE` for pattern matching

```
WHERE filter_id LIKE '% s'
```

but if you really want to find `% s` literally, use `=`

```
WHERE filter_id = '% s'
```

Comment: hi JW - thanks for the quick reply. When I add single quotes, I get almost the same error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: @nv39 can you execute this query only? `SELECT taba.id
  FROM 
   (
    SELECT  alum.id
    FROM  cvm_education AS edu
      INNER JOIN cvm_alumni AS alum
       ON alum.id = edu.alumni_id
    WHERE  cvm_alumni.profile_status = 1 AND 
      highest_edu IN 
      (
       SELECT  NAME
       FROM  cvm_filter_educationlevels
         INNER JOIN cvm_educationlevel AS edulevels
          ON educationlevel_id = edulevels.id
       WHERE  filter_id = '% s'
      )
   ) AS taba` ?

Comment: can you provide sample records with desired result?

Comment: no, sorry - weird situation: I didn't write it, I was only asked to figure out what's wrong with it

Comment: the complete error message when I run it on phpMyAdmin is the #1064 in the question

Answer (score 1):

The "`% s`" is invalid syntax. If that's a literal, then it needs to be enclosed in quotes:

```
WHERE filter_id = '% s'
```

(But that fix doesn't appear to be right. It almost looks as if the MySQL statement is being generated with a sprintf, and there was intended to be a '`%s`' placeholder that was supposed to be replaced with an value.)

Also, there's a closing parenthesis and alias missing from the end of the statement:

```
) foo
```

And this:

```
WHERE cvm_alumni.profile_status = 1
```

should be changed to this:

```
WHERE alum.profile_status = 1
```

(The table is assigned an alias, the column reference should be qualified with the alias, not the table_name)

It's also a good idea to qualify the references all column references, including `educationlevel_id`, `highest_edu` and `name`.  (That's not necessarily a problem with the statement, unless MySQL is throwing an "ambiguous column" error, but I prefer to insulate my statements from any "ambiguous column" error that will crop up when new columns are added.)

---

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id
  FROM (SELECT taba.id
          FROM (
                SELECT alum.id
                  FROM cvm_education edu
                  JOIN cvm_alumni alum
                    ON alum.id = edu.alumni_id
                 WHERE alum.profile_status = 1
                   AND `highest_edu` IN
                       (
                        SELECT `name`
                          FROM cvm_filter_educationlevels
                          JOIN cvm_educationlevel edulevels
                            ON `educationlevel_id` = edulevels.id
                         WHERE `filter_id` = '% s'
                       )
               ) taba
       ) foo
```

---

Comment: hi - thanks. I added quotes, a bracket before AS taba and make the change you said. I get this error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias